# Program that checks if number can be divided to three numbers

Tags: python

I need to make a program that checks if a number can be divided to three(or more) numbers. for example 8=2*2*2 and 153=3*3*17 and so on. And it has to work for all positive real numbers. I just can't wrap my head around it :(

```
 def loytyyko_kolme_tekijaa(luku):
    tekija = 2
    kaikki = 0
    while luku > tekija:
        if luku % tekija == 0:
            kaikki = kaikki + 1  
            tekija = tekija + 1 
    if kaikki >= 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Did you try something? Can you share that?

Comment: Please share if you tried something and also please elaborate on what is exactly the problem. It seems that you want to get three positive factors of a positive real number. What did you try to do? In which language?

Comment: Real numbers? How would you do a division test on 1.25?

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes. The problem is clear, the language as wellk (python flag!)... It is true it's more likely to get help if you have tried something yourself and show where you are stuck, but come on, people!

Comment: @Jblasco showing some effort is pretty much mandatory. Otherwise its just a code writing service.

Comment: ok so three or more numbers you say? How about looking for splitting integer into primes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550794/python-integer-factorization-into-primes/14551040

Comment: Now we see the effort, but what is the problem with your approach?

Comment: @Jblasco The problem is _not_ clear. It might be clear if it was about integers, but it says "for all positive real numbers"

Comment: @PaulRooney, not quite. Sometimes you just need to know how your problem is called to be able to google it and learn. Sometimes you have no clue how to start it, and maybe telling someone about '//' or '%'  in python will be of great help...

Comment: @khelwood, asking for clarification and downvoting are very different things. Don't see the point in downvoting without commenting, as well...

Comment: @Jblasco The point of downvoting is to indicate that a question is bad, for other people looking for questions or answers. Educating the asker is a side goal. And the OP has already been asked for clarification.

Comment: If a down vote comment is up voted it's a good indication of agreement from another down voter. Why rewrite the same comment if someone's already hit the nail on the head?

Answer (score 0):

Ok now that I see that you tried. Is this what you want?

Copied answer from here:
[Python - Integer Factorization into Primes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550794/python-integer-factorization-into-primes/14551040)

```
def factorize(num):
    for possible_factor in range(2, num):
        if num % possible_factor == 0:
            return [possible_factor] + factorize(num // possible_factor)
    return [num]

nums = [8,153]
for num in nums:
    print("{}: {}".format(num, factorize(num)))
```

Returns:

```
8: [2, 2, 2]
153: [3, 3, 17]
```